# How to reduce docker image size for Java application

Tags: java, docker, java-8, docker-multi-stage-build

i have the following dockerfile code but the image with over 500mb is way to large. I tried to use multi stage build in order so reduce the size but after that the kubernetes deployment wont work.

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/name_id.jar name_id.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT [ "java","-jar","name_id.jar" ]
```

With this file it works. Can someone help me?
For the project itself maven and springboot are used. I also have to clean install the jar everytime if i change something in the code.

Comment: You base image `openjdk:8` is 509 MB alone.

Comment: So How to reduce it?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, there are two things that come to mind when I think of minimizing the docker image

1. Base Images
2. Multistage Builds

**Le me try to answer your question**
I would used the small jdk image i.e openjdk:8-alpine
I would used this if I wanted to create the jar file inside the Dockerfile AND execute it. In you case, you just want to use an already existing jar file.

Since you already have and want to use the jar file named name_id.jar,
Then you just need the java runtime environment i.e openjdk:8-jre-alpine rather than openjdk:8-alpine

Comment: Actually i nerver heard of the second method. How would i creater the jar file inside of docker? Everytime i change something i have to mvn clean and mvn install the project so the jar is generated.

Comment: I would need more context about your project.
Generally, since you say its a maven project and would like to  create the jar inside the dockerdile
This is what I would recommend

Comment: For you base image, use maven:3.5.4-jdk-8-alpine rather than openjdk:8
WORKDIR /workingdir (this creates a working dir inside the container)
COPY . . (this copies all your project files)

After these, you can run any maven command that you ran on your project inside the Dockerfile eg mvn clean,mvn install
Inside the Dockerfile would be
RUN mvn clean
RUN,COPY are keywords just like the EXPOSE,FROM, ADD etc

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer i am quite new to this , so the dockerfile would look like this:?
`FROM maven:3.5.4-jdk-8-alpine as build
WORKDIR /workingdir 

From build
COPY src
run mvn clean
run mvn install
ADD target/name_id.jar name_id.jar
EXPOSE 8080`

would that be correct?

Comment: I know very little about your project but my thinkinh based on what you have give issomething like
`FROM maven:3.5.4-jdk-8-alpine 
WORKDIR /workingdir
COPY src .
RUN mvn clean
RUN mvn install/
java -jar name_id.jar
EXPOSE 8080`

Answer (score 0):

Can you use openjdk:8-alpine, size of the base image will be 144.9MB.

Use below image for less size
•   openjdk:8-jre-alpine: 84 MB

Or you can also try to install alpine os which is 5 MB and openjdk separately and check sizes

Comment: Thanks for the answer but isnt That also quite high ? I am only consuming one Rest api with some Business Logic as a microservice.

Comment: Hey thank u alot it worked out the image size is way less now.
But is there a way to use multi stage build get even less?
I am relativley new to this.